# Mercadopago API How to get currently subscribed customers for a subscription or plan

Tags: mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

I'm building a dashboard for a company using the [mercadopago REST API](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/api-docs/) as a payment gateway.  They have monthly subscribed customers to plans.

I was not able to find any method in the API to get current amount of subscribed users to a plan or subscription.

Is there a way to do this?

Its fells odd to tell my client to implement the subscription counter on their side.